# R - editing data frames in the list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a created a list of data frames using the code below. I would like to conduct following operations on this list:

1. Delete second row from each of the data frames
2. Merge the data frames by common identifier available in the first column

   ```
   files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
   library(plyr)
   list_dataframes <- llply(files, read.table, header = T, sep = ",")
   imax <- length(list_dataframes)
   i <- 1
   for (i in imax) {
           list_dataframes[[i]] = list_dataframes[[i]]
           i <- i + 1
       }
   ```

Comment: What is your `for` loop supposed to achieve (other than wasting CPU time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete second row from each of the data frames

```
list_dataframes <- lapply(list_dataframes, function(x) x[-2,])
```

Merge the data frames by common identifier available in the first column

```
DF <- Reduce(function(x ,y) merge(x, y, by=names(x)[1]), list_dataframes)
```

(Not tested due to lack of reproducible example.)